# Как работает метод join() в классе Thread

Tags: java, многопоточность

По идее метода `join()`, если я правильно его понимаю, он должен передавать управление программой тому потоку, на объекте которого был вызван, в то время как тот поток который этот вызов произвел, должен ждать.

Однако, если мы имеем несколько объектов потока, для которых идут вызовы метода `join()` подряд, то второй тоже запускается.

То есть, методе `main` мы имеем такой код:

```
    try {
        thread01.join();
        thread02.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

То по логике, сразу после выполнения вызова `thread01.join();`, метод `main` должен был остановиться и ждать пока `thread01` не вернет ему управление программой, но логирование показывает, что вместо этого, он выполняет еще и `thread02.join();` и только этого переходит в режим ожидания.

Почему так?

Это что означает, что метод `join()`, срабатывает только в тех случаях, когда после него не идет еще один `join()`, или тут блок `try`, имеет какой-то особый смысл? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Полный код потоков:

```
public class CounterOfSpace {
    private int counterOfSpaces;
    private int counterOfWords;
    private String text;
    private Thread thread01;
    private Thread thread02;

    public CounterOfSpace(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

        void startAll() {
            System.out.println("Start program");

            calcWords();
            calcSpaces();

            thread01.start();
            thread02.start();
            try {
                thread01.join();
                thread02.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Finish program");
        }

        private void calcSpaces() {
            thread01 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (text.length() == 0) return;
                    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                        if (c == ' ') {
                            counterOfSpaces++;
                            System.out.println("counterOfSpaces "+counterOfSpaces);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void calcWords() {
            thread02 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (text.length() == 0) return;
                    String[] words = text.split(" ");
                    for (String word : words) {
                        if (!word.equals(" ")) {
                            counterOfWords++;
                            System.out.println("counterOfWords "+counterOfWords);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Дайте код потоков. Мне почему то кажется что вы опять работает с "двумя словами". да нагрузите же вы свой процессор секунд на 10

Comment: Вроде бы всё правильно написано. Я бы попробовал ждать ожидание завершения потока через isAlive().

Comment: А как определяется, что thread01 еще не закончил выполнение на момент джойна? Согласен с предыдущим оратором, код потоков не помешал бы.

Comment: в смысле в `while (isAlive());`? Он же ресурсы не отпускает

Comment: @Victor вот добавил код я даю туда страницу текста и потоки  thread01 и thread02 работают синхронно потому что печетают на перебой друг другу.

Comment: Ну, все правильно. Вы стартовали 2 потока, и она начали независимую работу. Основной же поток остановился и ждет окончания сначала первого потока потом второго!

Comment: @Victor я так понял что если в каком-то поток вызывает метод join() у другого, то тот который этот вызов делает засыпает. Вот в коде выполнилась строка с thread1.join() значит поток который выполнил эту строку - уснул и на следующую строку thread2.join() прейти не может он же уже спит по идее, ан нет! не спит! а почему вот в этом то и вопрос. Я пытаюсь разобраться с принципами работы метода join()

Comment: А!!! Я понял!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> По идее метода join(), если я правильно его понимаю, он должен передавать управление программой тому потоку,

Это не совсем корректно, поток должен уходить в спящее состояние, а вот кому отдать управление решает шедулер.

> Однако, если мы имеем несколько объектов потока, для которых идут вызовы метода join() подряд, то второй тоже запускается.

Что никак не противоречит парадигме. В данном случае мы имеем три истории с двумя точками синхронизации:

```
Main      Thread1             Thread2
<init>    <init>              <init>
running   running? finished?  running? finished?
join t1   finished            running? finished?
join t2   finished            finished
```

Данный код гарантирует, что после завершения t1.join поток t1 будет завершен, но не гарантирует, что он не завершится до вызова t1.join, что очевидно и происходит в этом случае. К моменту вызова t1.join поток t1 может быть в любом состоянии, даже если ему приходится считать тяжелые данные продолжительное время - формально это разрешено, хоть на практике такое будет встречаться нечасто. Вкупе с

> логирование показывает

это говорит о том, что, скорее всего, поток просто очень быстро заканчивает работу, а вы принимаете это за несоответствующий спецификации феномен. В таких проблемах не стоит полагаться на логирование, потому что его синхронизационные отношения по отношению к основной программе туманны, и для меня не было бы неожиданным несоблюдение порядка строчек в выводе или длительные (относительно происходящих в программе процессов) задержки при выводе. Также стоит умеренно полагаться на временные замеры подобных вещей, потому что стандартный источник времени может быть не монотонным и возвращать меньшие значения на последующие вызовы, в результате чего будет выглядеть, будто программа выполняется в обратном порядке.

При желании можно заглянуть в [исходный код](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l1233) Thread и увидеть, что join реализован через wait и защищен isAlive-гардами от случайных пробуждений, поэтому метод join вернет не раньше, чем поток перестанет возвращать true на isAlive.

Comment: >>>Что никак не противоречит парадигме<< как не противоречит выполнилась строка с thread1.join() значит поток который выполнил эту строку - уснул и на следующую строку thread2.join() прейти не может он же уже спит по идее, ан нет! не спит! а почему вот в этом то и вопрос.

Comment: >>>это говорит о том, что, скорее всего, поток просто очень быстро заканчивает работу,<<< нет там каждый поток печатаен несколько страниц текста каждый свое. И делают это в перемешку на перебой.

Comment: @Павел или спит 0 секунд. Если вы заглянете в исходники, то убедитесь, что из метода join можно выйти только за счет окончания потока или InterruptedException.

Answer (score 0):

Расставить в такой последовательности и все прояснится:

```
старт
джойн
старт
джойн
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]